# ASP.NET Core. Получение локального пути к файлу

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Я делаю `TagHelper`, чтобы встраивать стили или линковать их, параметром
передаю `@Url.Content("~/css/file.css")`, т.е. относительный путь вместе с именем хоста, не понимаю как получить локальный путь относительно `_webHostEnvironment.WebRootFileProvider` без костылей.

пример:
на вход строка `/mywebsite/css/file.css` или `https://localhost:5001/mywebsite/css/file.css`
хочу получить локальный путь от wwwroot: `/css/file.css`

Comment: Скажите что в строке есть, и что должно быть?

Comment: Вам надо получать локальный путь к файлу в файловой системе из пути запроса или нет? Неясно из вопроса.

Comment: @aepot добавил пример

Comment: @SerafimProzorov да, есть веб путь относительно домена. хочу получить путь в файловой системе

Comment: @dgzargo, псмотрите, ответы на этот вопрос помогут Вам?

Comment: Если работать как со строкой, то как-то так `string site = "mysebsite"; string path = url.Substring(url.IndexOf(site) + site.Length + 1);`.

Comment: @aepot не хочется хардкодить название сайта

Comment: не надо хардкодить, получите его из окружения

Comment: @SerafimProzorov где-то должна была быть ссылка?

Comment: @aepot, да :) Вот эта: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49398965/what-is-the-equivalent-of-server-mappath-in-asp-net-core

Comment: @SerafimProzorov мне нужен способ как сделать `URL.Content` наоборот. придумал максимально простое объяснение хах)